How to Log Each Outbound TCP Connection
At my company we have a set of 3 identical VMs.  These VMs house an app that "sends messages".  The app sends each message by making a TCP connection out to one of two fixed IP addresses (let's say A.B.C.D and E.F.G.H).  So it goes like this:

Establish connection
Transmit message
Close connection

and so on.  This app is single-threaded, but multiple copies of the app run as separate processes, up to 5 at a time per VM.  Lots of messages are sent per day, on the order of 50,000 on a "medium" day.  The message sending is spread evenly across the 3 VMs.
The app is sending to a DNS name, and the A.B.C.D and E.F.G.H addresses are the only two we ever see on resolution.  Moreover, the DNS name is a CNAME to xxx.awsglobalaccelerator.com and I know global accelerators have 2 fixed IP addresses.  So I think we're OK on this assumption of these two particular IP addresses.
Anyway, we have trouble with this app.  Always have.  Messages get rejected a lot (20% or so).  The receiver of the messages (a different company from ours) claims we are hitting some sort of limit on their firewall.  They say the limit is with the number of simultaneous TCP connections.  They are being cagey about what that limit actually is.  Anyway seems like we should only be sending a max of 15 simultaneous messages (3 VMs x 5 processes each), and that isn't much at all.  Also, the problem ONLY happens in the first couple of hours of early afternoon.  So I think they are full of beans.
The VMs are Rocky Linux 9, patches are current-ish (within a month or so).  I go on the VMs and look at ss and grep for the destination IP addresses and I see maybe one or two per VM, ever.  I figure these connections are of very short duration (they SHOULD be, at least), so this doesn't surprise me.  But I guess this confirms that the connections are not "building up" in some state like "FIN-WAIT" or something.  I have a script running this ss |grep every minute of the day and and reporting up thru telegraf / influxDB / grafana .
This should be enough to rub the other company's nose in, but I want to go further and check the number of outgoing connections.  Here's where I run into trouble.  I obviously can't use ss or netstat (they are the same now, no?) because the connections are so short-lived so i have to use the linux firewall.  I first tried using firewalld rich rules like this:
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 destination address=A.B.C.D/32 port port=443 protocol=tcp log prefix="GOT-EM-1 " level=debug accept'
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 destination address=E.F.G.H/32 port port=443 protocol=tcp log prefix="GOT-EM-2 " level=debug accept'

But nothing was ever logged.  After removing the destination address part I could see that apparently all I was seeing was return traffic, because all I ever saw was traffic to my IP address. So I guess I was doing it wrong.  But I couldn't figure out how to do it right so I fell back to good ol' iptables like this:
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -d A.B.C.D/32 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "GOT-EM-1 "
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -d E.F.G.H/32 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "GOT-EM-2 "

This looked a lot more promising.  I could see LOTS of log entries.  But I showed the app dev and he then told me my counts are wrong.  For instance, yesterday the app said we sent 50K messages, with 40K successes and 10K failures.  But I only counted 35K TCP connections.  WTF?
So am I doing it wrong again?  How do I count the number of outbound connections to a given IP address over time?

It is conceivable that you are seeing port reuse on the sending side resulting in the state not being NEW.  Try detecting SYN packets instead.  (See the --syn flag in iptables-extensions(8).)

@DavidG. thanks so much.  today i have changed my iptables config to iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -d A.B.C.D/32 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "GOT-EM-1 ", etc.  we'll see how it goes today.

Hope it works.  It occurs to me that you might see some retransmissions in this case, so two packets with matching ports that differ by only a few seconds could represent only one connection.
